# BSC full node have more states than reason

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc, full-node

I'm currently trying to setup a BSC full node on an AWS EC2 `i3en.xlarge` (so the config should be OK).

I've follow these steps : https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html
Note that I've started from genesis block since 5 days.

But now when I run `eth.syncing` from `geth attach` I got this :

```
{
  currentBlock: 13303893,
  highestBlock: 13304008,
  knownStates: 367366624,
  pulledStates: 367336511,
  startingBlock: 13190203
}
```

It's make me crazy because these is not so much state in BSC.

I can say that because on a synced node (quicknode) I got theses values :

```
{
    StartingBlock: 13304096,
    CurrentBlock: 13304107,
    HighestBlock: 13304098,
    PulledStates: 297473485,
    KnownStates: 297473485
}

// Got these value with
web3.subscribe('syncing', (err, result) => console.log(result));
```

Is someone already facing this issue ? Is it just a missunderstand about states (maybe it's because the quicknode is pruned) ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a full explanation, but I know that the number of states will vary from node to node. You can't know in advance how much states your node will have when it finishes syncing and it will not be the same as other nodes.

For BSC, you really want to start syncing from the [official snapshot](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc-snapshots). Otherwise it will take forever.

Comment: Ahhh, blockchain curiosities... I have givup starting from snapshot because I've launched 2 node, one from genesis, one from snapshot but the genesis one was ahead of the snapshot one (in term of states), but now I understand that it probably doesn't mean anything...